# Django reset password link gives 404

Tags: python, django

I have implemented django_reset_password functionality.

Everything is running perfectly on localhost but when I am running the same thing on server, the link that i get in the email says 404 on server.

```
path('password_reset/', password_reset, name='auth_password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', password_reset_done, name='auth_password_reset_done'),
path('reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/',
     password_reset_confirm, name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', password_reset_complete, name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
```

"auth_password_reset_confirm" is the function in which I am getting 404 on server.

> http://testing.xyz.com/auth/reset/(%3FPNg%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FP5id-91751fc793227bd46093%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/

Above link gives 404

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/reset/(%3FPNg%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FP5id-91751fc793227bd46093%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/

But this same url works in localhost.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are all routes malfunctions on the server compared to the localhost environment?

Comment: Yes, there is no specification done for server links

Comment: Did you check your setup.py? Check your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.

Comment: ["*"] - Allowed for all
And it this was the problem I would not have got 404 error

Comment: well you have a point.. I don't have idea why it responds 404

Answer (score 3):

Well I thought I am using django 2.2 so I should use 'path' instead of 'url'
But then this above error came.

So I converted my 'path' to 'url', and it worked.

From this:

```
path('password_reset/', password_reset, name='auth_password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', password_reset_done, name='auth_password_reset_done'),
path('reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/',
     password_reset_confirm, name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', password_reset_complete, name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
```

To this:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', password_reset, name='auth_password_reset'),
url(r'^password_reset/done/$', password_reset_done, name='auth_password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$',
     password_reset_confirm, name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset/done/$', password_reset_complete, name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
```

And it worked!!